How to Create a Generic Semantic Data Model in Tabular Editor for Power BI Reports with Separate Datasets?
I’m working on a Proof of Concept (POC) to create a generic semantic data model using Tabular Editor that connects to multiple datasets for Power BI reports. The goal is to have one centralized semantic data model deployed in Tabular Editor while allowing Power BI reports to use their respective datasets.
Key Objectives:
A single semantic model is to be maintained and deployed in Tabular Editor.
Different Power BI reports are connected to their own datasets.
Ensure flexibility in data source connectivity while keeping the semantic model generic and reusable.
Challenges:
How to architect the connections between the semantic model and multiple datasets.
Maintaining data consistency and ensuring no redundant model deployments.
I’d like to know if anyone in the community has achieved a similar setup and can share guidance or best practices for implementing this approach. Specifically:
Can this be achieved with perspectives, calculation groups, or other advanced features of Tabular Editor?
Are there any considerations for managing relationships, partitions, or dataset-specific logic in this setup?
I appreciate any insights, examples, or references you can share. Thank you!

I'm confused by what you're asking.  A "Semantic Model" and a "Dataset" are the same thing. Perhaps you mean a Composite Model? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models

Thank you for your consideration. Let me explain it again. I have the data of 3 different clients but powerBi reports are same. so my aim is to create one model in tabular editor which will be connected separately each dataset. and reports are also separately for each clients. but on backend there is just one model in tabular editor , if i create new measure then this new measure will be available for all three clients. i hope you get my point. still if you need some information then i will try to explain it in more depth. thank you!

You should create a single master model, and deploy three copies of it, each connected to a single client’s data.
A common approach is to have a separate workspace for each client.

Thank you for your suggestion. if you not mind can you please give me short over view how can i achieve this goal? your guidelines really important for me. @David Browne - Microsoft

See, eg https://powerbidevcamp.powerappsportals.com/sessions/session20/

I appreciate your consideration. I watched the session, which provides practical demonstrations and code examples to illustrate the implementation process. This makes it a valuable resource for developers and administrators looking to scale multi-tenant solutions in Power BI. However, I aim to use one model in the Tabular editor.

Yea, don't do that.  Create a single "master model" and deploy three copies of it to three different workspaces.

Thank you for your reply, can you please help me to understand this model? if I create one model and deploy it into three different workspaces and later on I need to modify it then will I make change it into 3 workspaces?
